# Given an LP has a feasible solution, how best to check if it has an optimal solution?

Tags: linear-programming, simplex

I have an LP in equation form and I'm already given that the feasible set in nonempty. What would be a good algorithm to check if the feasible set is bounded? In other words, given that the feasible set is nonempty, what would be the best algorithm to check if it's bounded? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If in two space, graph. But for higher dimensions, the simplex algorithm will wind up telling you if the objective function is unbounded (I forget the details but you could google it.)

Comment: I'm too lazy to type the answer.  You may see [this example](http://image.slidesharecdn.com/specialcasesinsimplex-150418020305-conversion-gate02/95/special-cases-in-simplex-method-10-638.jpg?cb=1429322690)